# как по клику на кнопку вывести на печать во всплывающем окне страницу другую? jquery js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

на одно й странице таблица со списком товаров и у каждой строки кнопки 'print' на нажатее которой хочу сделать чтобы на эту же страницу вывелось окно для печати того товара на который кликнули

Могу предположить сделать ajax запрос по клику на кнопки 'print' чтобы получить полную инфу о товаре , далее нужно вставить на html станицу и показать пользователю уже window.print(); с этой инфой

```html
<table>
  <row>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td class="print">Print</td>
  </row>
  <row>
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td class="print">Print</td>
  </row>
  <row>
    <td>Name3</td>
    <td class="print">Print</td>
  </row>
</table>

<script>
        window.print();
</script>
```

Comment: а редирект на станицу, а там window.print(); ?

Comment: я сделл что переходим просто по ссылке print на страницу этого товвара а там window.print(); ну оно получается сразу загружается страница а потом всплывает окно ак бы некрасиво 2 раза показывается товар

Comment: после печати сразу редирект обратно